# Why doesn't ICriteria pass variable value to the withClause?

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

I'm trying to restrict a left outer join with a simple restriction but it fails with an sql exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@p1".

My ICriteria:

```
 var r = session.CreateCriteria<Parent>("p")
.CreateCriteria("p.Children", "c", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Eq("c.Name", "John Doe"))
.List();
```

The desired SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Parents p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Children c ON c.ParentID = p.ID AND c.Name = 'John Doe'
```

Do I have to add the variable values in any way? The SQL generated by NHibernate is correct but the variable just isn't sent to the server.

Comment: I got this too: Must declare the variable '@p19'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may have found a bug in NHibernate ICriteria where you join with LeftOuterJoin on one collection but entity has two or more collections. In this case it will generate joins with 'and' on both collections with two parameters, but only supply one. And database will throw:

```
Insufficient parameters supplied to the command
```

It might be a good idea to [open a bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa). In the mean time, this is supported with HQL:

```
var query = session.CreateQuery(
  "select p from Parent p left outer join p.Children as c with c.Name = :name");

query.SetString("name", "John Doe");
var parents = query.List<Parent>();
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to use a left join retrieve all Parents even if they have no children?

Comment: Yes but it adds the restriction to the WHERE-clause, I need it to be on the ON-clause in join itself. Otherwise I have to create a disjunction to keep rows where the join has no match.

Comment: I'll go with the HQL. Thank you!